# how to make REST request with iron-ajax using user input

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, polymer

I am trying to provide several dropdown selection menu and a button for the webpage. When the button is clicked, a POST request with JSON object will be sent to an url and response with JSON object with be returned. Is this functionality supported by iron-ajax?

The document shows that the `params` can be used to set the JSON object. Is the logic as follows?

- set `params` of the iron-ajax to some variable of the DOM
- write a `buttonClicked()` function for the button press, and it updates the variables of the DOM from dropdown section menu, and calls the `generateRequest()` method of the iron-ajax

The example from the document is shown as follows

`<iron-ajax
    auto
    url="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search"
    params='{"part":"snippet", "q":"polymer", "key": "YOUTUBE_API_KEY", "type": "video"}'
    handle-as="json"
    on-response="handleResponse"
    debounce-duration="300"></iron-ajax>`

Given the described strategy works, the questions I have are

- do I delete `auto` to avoid it sending request automatically?
- does the `params` assignment look something like `params= '{{myJsonString}}'`
- how to call the `generateRequest()` of a specific iron-ajax object (assuming there are multiple iron-ajax tags in the page)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> do I delete auto to avoid it sending request automatically?

Yes

> does the params assignment look something like params=
>   '{{myJsonString}}'

remove single quotes: 
**`params="[[myJsonObject]]"`**
myJsonObject is a normal javascript object like:

```
{
  param1 : 'param1 value',
  param2 : 'param2 value'
}
```

note that you must use a javascript object not its string if you want to bind to params attribute.

> how to call the generateRequest() of a specific iron-ajax object
>   (assuming there are multiple iron-ajax tags in the page)?

you can assign an id to your iron-ajax tag:

```
<iron-ajax id="myAjax1"
    auto
    url="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search"
    params='{"part":"snippet", "q":"polymer", "key": "YOUTUBE_API_KEY", "type": "video"}'
    handle-as="json"
    on-response="handleResponse"
    debounce-duration="300"></iron-ajax>
```

And get it from your javascript code like this:

```
this.$.myAjax1
```

Comment: Could you also show me how `myJsonObject` look like? Thanks very much.

Comment: simple javascript object defined in properties (will update my answer)